# Permissions error within docker image running from Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am attempting to automate our conda build process, by attempting to have it run within a docker image, that runs within jenkins. However, I'm getting a permissions error when our tool attempts to access a directory.

When I run the tool on my local machine, I get no error.

Jenkins error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/build-dir/work'

Docker file to create docker image contains:

```
RUN \
    sudo -E mkdir /home/build-dir/ \
    && sudo -E chmod 666 /home/build-dir/ \
    && sudo -E mkdir /home/build-dir/work/ \
    && sudo -E chmod 666 /home/build-dir/work/ \
    && /home/jenkins/miniconda3/bin/conda install conda-build \
    && /home/jenkins/miniconda3/bin/conda env create --name molPy -f /linux-environment.yml
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {

  image = docker.image("x.com/molpy:dev")
  image.pull()
  image.inside("--privileged") {
    withEnv(['HOME=.']) {

      stage ('Checkout Code') {
        checkout scm
        sh 'git branch'
        sh 'git log HEAD^..HEAD'
      }

      stage ('Conda Build') {
        try {
          sh 'echo $PWD'
          sh 'bash -c "source /home/jenkins/miniconda3/bin/activate molPy && open-builder --build-dir=\'/home/build-dir/\' --output-dir=\'/home/output-dir\' --conversions=osx-64"'
        } catch(err) {
          currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
          throw err
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the tool run as the jenkins user and is trying to access the home dir of build-user?

If so, /home/build-dir/ may need execute permissions for Others (`chmod 667`) in order for the tool to access the directory. Permissions can be changed back after tool finishes.